# .NET 4.0 WebAPI on IIS6: Starts returning 404 until ApplicationPool restart

Tags: .net-4.0, iis-6, asp.net-web-api

We have a .NET 4.0 ASP.NET WebForms website and mixed ASMX/WebAPI webservice deployed to a Windows Server 2003 IIS 6.0 instance that is suffering from 404s being retuned from the WebAPI controllers for various periods of time.

The WebAPI controllers are in the same project/site as the ASMX service, however, the ASMX service has no issues. Both the webservice and WebForms website are hosted in the same ApplicationPool, though are separate IIS sites.

A snippet of the IIS logs is below, where the WebAPI service seems to recover by itself :

[image]

When this error has occurred recycling the ApplicationPool has done the trick, though sometimes it appears that an ApplicationPool recycle actually starts the problem. It has happened once or twice immediately after a recycle after a new deployment. A second recycle fixes the issue. I have turned off periodic ApplicationPool recycling to see if this stops the issue.

I am not really sure where I should be looking from here...

Comment: I have a similar problem with Web API2 and IIS8.5. We start getting 404 after some random period and restarting the application pool fixes the issue. Did you find any solution?